# Tweepy not returning all tweets?

Tags: twitter, tweepy

I am trying to simply get `n` tweets for a given `query`. The problem is, tweepy keeps returning `tweets < n` when I do this via cursor method.

I think this has something to do rate limiting. Though I initialized the api to wait on the rate limit, and tell me when this is happening.

Here's my code.

```
# Initialize API
ckey = "xxx"
csecret = "xxx"
atoken = "xxx"
asecret = "xxx"
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(ckey, csecret)
auth.set_access_token(atoken, asecret)
api = tweepy.API(auth, wait_on_rate_limit=True, wait_on_rate_limit_notify=True)

max_tweets = 1000
query = 'tweepy'

l = []
for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.search, q=query).items(max_tweets):
  l.append(tweet.text)

print(len(l))
```

And it always happens that `l` has less tweets than `max_tweets`.

Answer (score 0):

It’s due to the query, try different query instead of tweety may be there is no enough tweets in last seven days. I just tried different query getting 1000 tweets as requested.